# Python vs NodeJS web applications from a security point of view

Tags: python, django, node.js, security, express

I am planning to build a web application which is security critical and I need to decide what technology to use on the back end.
The options I am considering are Python (mostly with the Django framework) and NodeJS (possibly with express.js). From the security point of view I would like to know the pros and cons of using each of these technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Python Flask for small projects. I'm assuming it's small because node.js is usually used for real-live-updates and realtime chatting and other javascript based apps. The advantage is polling/broadcasts from server to clients rather than 100s of individual requests being handled.

Security-wise, javascript apps can be abused without even using tools if they spam your servers but that is something you should handle on the web server or simply make sure spams are controlled and blocked if being repeated in an inhumane speed.

Comment: I am planning to build a polling mechanism and it should contain everything ranging from the candidates listing the agenda and discussion on it, to voting and declaring results. So, which one should I use ?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I'm not super expert on the topic, but I have worked a bit with both Node and Django.

I'd say that it pretty much depends what you're doing and how you set everything up, but with Django you're pretty much forced to set it up on Apache/Gunicorn (w/ NGinx) so you have that extra layer there that you can use to have an additional layer of security, and Django has a lot of built in packages to help with authentication / users / etc.

But honestly it boils down to how well structured your application is.  I'd personally prefer python for building a secure application as for me it's easier to wrap my head around OOP logic in python moreso than trying to structure all your callbacks correctly in node.

Answer (score 0):

Although JavaScript can be abused and errors can be missed. Node.js with Typescript is a great option. Python has great libraries. I would say go with which ever makes you comfortable at the start. Both require loads of testing if the project needs to be secure anyway.